# Onsen UIとjQuery Mobileを組合せた場合における制限の有無について

Tags: onsen-ui, cordova, jquery-mobile

Onsen UIとjQuery Mobileを組合せてHTML5ハイブリッドアプリを開発した際に、
何か制限などはあるのでしょうか？
全体としては、PhoneGap+Onsen UI+jQuery Mobile+Backbone.jsでの実装を考えています。

Onsen UI側、jQuery Mobile側どちらかで制限が出てしまう場合は
事前に把握しておきたいため、質問致しました。

HTML5ハイブリッドアプリ開発が初めてのため、教えて頂けると嬉しいです！
宜しくお願い致します！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnsenUIというのはAngularJSを土台にして作られたUIフレームワークです。OnsenUIをお使いになるのでしたら、MVCフレームワークとしてAngularJSの恩恵を受けられますので、あえて別のMVCフレームワークであるBackbone.jsを導入する必要性は薄いように思います。また、jQuery mobileはWebアプリ用のUIフレームワークであり、一般的に動作がやや重たいと言われているようです。同じUIフレームワークであるOnsenUIとjQuery mobileを併用すると、単純に考えて参照するドキュメントは倍になりますしメンテナンス性が落ちます。もしもjQuery mobileを使用する明確な理由が無く、OnsenUIでの開発に興味をお持ちなのでしたら、OnsenUI一本で開発することをおすすめします。

Comment: OnsenUIに無くて、jQueryモバイルにあるものとかもあるので、片方だけでっていうのは結構しんどくなるっていうのが経験則です・・・そして、今回はCORDOVA使うということなので、速度については大丈夫かなと。あと、backboneJSとangularでは修得するまでの時間がまったく違うので、angularを真剣に覚えるならOKだと思いますが、片方に寄せるっていうのは結構たいへんかもです。

Comment: やはり異なるフレームワークを共存させるより、1つに統一して開発する方が良さそうですね。citherさん、Kawaiさん、コメント頂きありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

Monaca基盤なのかによりますが、既存のコンポーネントのセット内容を理解しておかないと、仕様なのかバグなのかわからないと思います。jQueryユーザに多いと思いますが、OnsenUIの癖を理解して作らないと変な隙間が生まれるとかが発生します。今回はangularJSを使わないようなので、問題なさそうですが、組み合わせによって挙動がイマイチわからないことがありますので、標準的な実装を心がけるとうまくいくと思います。

Comment: Kawaiさん、ご教授頂き、ありがとうございます！
追加での質問となってしまいますが、「使用なのかバグなのかわからない」に関して、PhoneGap/Cordova（Monacaではなく）基盤の場合はエラーが出ても原因を特定できるということでしょうか（初心者のため。。）？また、「変な隙間」とはどんなことなのか、もう少し噛み砕いて教えて頂けませんか？何卒、宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: toolbarやtabbar等の下にons-pageが表示されてしまう、つまり画面幅を明確に固定できない等です。普通にやると起こらないです。angular使うと発生するだけです。＞変な隙間  MonacaでやるとMonacaでどこまで実装されているのかが把握するのに時間がかかったということであって、わからないわけではなく、それはどんなプログラムでも一緒だと主ますが、仕様をよく読んで作っていただければと思います。MonacaだとjQuery2.03を先に入れると、jQueryモバイルが入らず、挙動がおかしくなるなどの問題があるので、そう言う相互依存関係を無視したいのであればご自身で環境構築される方がよいと思います。

Comment: 丁寧にお教え頂き、ありがとうございます。頂いた情報をもとに検討を進めさせて頂きます！

Comment: スタックオーバーフローでは、納得したら▲ボタンを押すことで評価できますのでそれでこの質問をクローズできます。